# No such file 'main.o' error when execute make

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following files all in the same directory.

```
.
├── Makefile
├── lexer.cpp
├── lexer.h
├── parser.cpp
├── parser.h
├── main.cpp
```

`main.cpp` depends on `parser.h` and `lexer.h`.

`lexer.cpp` depends on `lexer.h`

`parser.cpp` depends on `parser.h` which in turn depends on `lexer.h`.

I have a Makefile to compile the files and link them as follows.

```
all: main

main: main.o lexer.o parser.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ mccomp.o lexer.o parser.o

main.o: main.cpp lexer.h parser.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c lexer.h parser.h

lexer.o: lexer.cpp lexer.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c lexer.h

parser.o: parser.cpp parser.h lexer.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c parser.h lexer.h

clean:
    rm -rf main
```

When I execute `make` I get the following error.

```
clang-11: error: no such file or directory: 'main.o'
clang-11: error: no such file or directory: 'lexer.o'
clang-11: error: no such file or directory: 'parser.o'
```

I don't know why this is happening given that the `%.o` rules should have generated these files. How do I fix this?

Comment: None of the rules for generating .o files actually mention the cpp file they're supposed to compile. Add the .cpp file (or the magic variable `$<`) to the recipe instead of all the header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the rules for generating .o files actually mention the cpp file they're supposed to compile. Add the .cpp file (or the magic variable `$<`) to the recipe instead of all the header files:

```
main.o: main.cpp lexer.h parser.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o $@
```

or

```
main.o: main.cpp lexer.h parser.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Also note that there is a built-in rule for compiling .cpp files, so it suffices to state the dependencies:

```
main.o: main.cpp lexer.h parser.h
lexer.o: lexer.cpp lexer.h
parser.o: parser.cpp parser.h lexer.h
```

Make will then recompile the .o files if one of the input files changes. Note that it uses `CXXFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`.

Comment: It's a good idea to explicitly tell the compiler what you want the output file to be, as well: `-o $@`.  The compiler will usually "guess right" by replacing the suffix of the source file with `.o` but it's better to be specific.  Also, those error messages look weird to me: `clang-11` is a C compiler but this makefile appears to be trying to compile C++ code.  Odd.

Comment: Good point, edited.